# What is the name in Pāli and Sanskrit for the ‘body scanning’ meditation technique?

Tags: vipassana, terminology, meditation-body, pali

I would like to research this method in historical texts, but any search on google for ‘body scan’ only returns results related to the modern vipassana movement.

Comment: Is is there in the MahaSatiPatthana Sutta ?

Comment: So far as I know... A particular "scanning " technique is not from the suttas (all of which only ask for witnessing rise and passing away of sensations amongst the other three)... But from the Burmese school..definately UBa Khin.

Comment: By historical text, my interest is not limited to sutras but also any commentary, termas, or other references—just anything that isn't related to the modern vipassana movement. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what my apprehension is : Are we sure this term is not coined by the modern vipassana movement.Why don't you email the SN Goenka website.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technique.  Are you referring to the scanning of the body as per the Mahasatipattha Sutta?  The section on Kayanupassana includes mindfulness of breathing, mindfulness of the postures, contemplation of impurities (i.e. the organs, bone, skin, teeth, bodily fluids, etc.), and some others.

Comment: While I think the technique is most commonly experienced by attendees of Goenka’s 10-day vipassana retreats I have also heard it from other Theravada teachers. [This article](http://gurmeet.net/spiritual/vipassana-meditation-by-s-n-goenka-part-iii/) includes a description of it in the Goenka style, but therein it is generically called “vipassanā meditation”. The practice is obviously applied as part of the four applications of mindfulness (Satipatthana Sutta)—to the body, observing tactile sensations without mental projections—which is core vipassana, but the “scanning” modality, is it modern?

Comment: SNGoenka is very particular about the scanning part which has to be done consciously...Whereas Mahasatpatthana sutta only asks the monk to be aware of the sensations.

Answer (score 2):

[Kayagata-sati Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html).  Buddha was explicit that breathing is part of the body, so anapanasati is a sub-set of body scanning.

Comment: kaya = body, kayagata = relating to body

Comment: Spelled *kāya* according to [the PTS dictionary](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.1:1:474.pali)

Comment: i'm on a roll ( :-) )(my observation) ; anapanasati is a sub-set of kayagata-sati.  kayagata-sati is a sub-set of four satipatthana.  four satipatthana is a part of magga 8.  magga 8 is part of four noble thruths.

Comment: @dean alkas I guess it ends with the Four Nobel Truths.

Comment: @ Uilium , i think 4 noble truths is part of dhamma (nature)  .. almost certain.   again, my observation.  not sure if dhamma is part of anything else tho.

Answer (score 1):

"Kayanupassana" comming under "Chathu Satipatthana". You can find detailed discription in ["Maha Satipatthana Sutta"](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.22.0.than.html)

Also refer and search for "Anapanasati Meditation".

Refer:http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html

Comment: Which part of Maha Satipatthana Sutta are you referring to?

Comment: To the part that explains about "Kayanupassana"

Comment: I searched for "Kayanupassana" in the translation you linked to and didn't find anything. Could you tell me how to find it in the document?

Comment: Please refer to "Body" section. http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.22.0.than.html#body